# Performance issues between Windows Mobile and Windows CE?

Tags: performance, windows-mobile, compact-framework, windows-ce

I've an application that is performing poorly on a Windows Mobile device, but performs decently on a Windows CE device. I was wondering if there were any known performance issues I should look out for between the two platforms?

Specifically I'm looking at winforms interaction. I seems the UI is sluggish, I will edit this post again once I get specifics on the hardware. From what I understand, the device running Windows Mobile is pretty beefy, and the device running CE is older/slower, however the CE device is more responsive.

The code uses the 3.5 Compact Framework.

Comment: Is it written in native code, or using the .NET Compact Framework?

Comment: For others who come across this link, we benchmarked a device with the same identified processor (and presumably other hardware) with WinCE 5.0 and Windows Mobile 6.5 (CE 5.2.29336) using BMQ and found the WinCE to be many times faster in all respects.

BMQ downloaded from here: 
http://www.hpcfactor.com/scl/details.asp?id=419&page=download

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a whole host of possible differences.  First, Windows Mobile *is* Windows CE (version 5.0) so fundamentally there is no difference.

Now if you're comparing WinMo to say a CE 6.0 device, there will be some differences in kernel thunking performance, but generally speaking if you have identical hardware and identical drivers on top of that hardware, you'll have identical performance.

You've given us little to go on as to what, exactly, is performing poorly.  Disk writes?  Video rendering? Serial port throughput?  I could think of a hundred items that might be different between the two possible platforms.  The key is that you have to be comparing apples to apples.  For example if you look at video rendering speed, are both devices using the same color depth and resolution?  Are they both using the same graphics driver (separate hardware acceleration v. using the processor itself)?  Do they have the same meory?  The same processor architecture?  The same processor speed?

Give us a little more info and we might be able to narrow things down.

Comment: I have embellished my question a bit. Sorry for being vague, I'd posted this question in a rush.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, Windows Mobile is just WindowsCE with some extra GUI elements added on.  The differences are not significant as far as code execution speed.  What is probably more relevant is CPU architecture and speed.  Do the 2 devices use the same CPU running at the same speed?  If not, then the comparison is not valid.